# Having issue undestanding components properties with generic types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to handle generic types when receiving component properties in Typescript and React.
For example, here I am trying to make sure that the type of `options` in the `columns` property of the `SubComponent` component is inherited from the generic type `OptionsAB` of the object passed to `optionSet`: `PropertiesAB`.

Here the code I'm testing

```
interface OptionSet<T> {
  options: T[];
}

interface SubComponentProps<TFilter = unknown> {
  columns: {
    optionSet: OptionSet<TFilter>;
    options: TFilter;
  }[];
}

export function SubComponent<TFilter = unknown>(_: SubComponentProps<TFilter>) {
  return null;
}

interface OptionsAB {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
interface OptionsCS {
  c: string;
  s: string;
}
const PropertiesAB: OptionSet<OptionsAB> = { options: [] };
const PropertiesCS: OptionSet<OptionsCS> = { options: [] };

export const MainComponent = () => {
  return (
    <SubComponent
      columns={[
        { optionSet: PropertiesAB, options: { a: "b", b: "s" } }, // This should work
        { optionSet: PropertiesAB, options: { a: "b" } }, // This should throw error
        { optionSet: PropertiesCS, options: { a: "b" } }, // This should throw error
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

But the type of `options` is always `unknown`. And the type of `optionSet` is also read as `OptionSet<unknown>` and not `OptionSet<OptionsAB>`

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of your problem, is that typescript generic will infer type from the most "shallow" generic.. in your case:

```
interface SubComponentProps<TFilter = unknown> {
  columns: {
    optionSet: OptionSet<TFilter>;
    options: TFilter; <<here
  }[];
}
```

in new typescript there will be new `NoInfer` helper type and it should work...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.5.0-dev.20240307#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgMoRgA8AKgHzIDeAUMstpjiAM4BcyJA2gLoDc1AX2rVQkWIhR4ArgCMAwtgC26XBHAAFKA2akAYsAA2Y5AF5kUkAGsQ2AO4gKNOgmwGpiluyd16jXATB2DCx-Qj1DMTJ%20H18Qz2QAOWwASRAYaHCjaCjaZAEefiFqCAAPFSgwZBgLBDjkaXklFRA1YhJ9LKhTcysbezIACgB9dgaFZVUNLXQddojsgEoqXKhCKSgQZBApAwNC4VFoeCQ0PxYAQQAhZbo4dmYwKFAAc2jkGXvHl-3D8RPgpjMOR4G7IBCfJ4gV65NjIB6Q6FCFwsSqaBjQLAQZhXIJnAJEAG4bGXChmSixQHsHh5fjIh7INHoDHALHA3FxfGEljA0lUClEqncGnCUrlSp0yoAWTgoHGzVa3QGSxMjhWaw2yAGuToRDGTUmYG1Phcbg8zBMlE4Rpi5IYHMI7EZzKxVwANPz4uS7sgAEQyH3uj6%205g%20vJ5d0AegjHAAFsBmHCY9gdgATZC2bBQSzWny2vEOhnTZ3E912yl871%200MCcPIKOx%20OJ5MGNNgGNaWzIaBaKA5uh5%202BQvoiosoF4UtnWFe9hVsMCSPRkhxhPMJOp5BtjtdqA9nPcIQxCNkXILQq8IA)

currently you can use some custom helper type like:

```
export type NoInfer<A extends any> =
    [A][A extends any ? 0 : never]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgMoRgA8AKgHzIDeAUMstpjiAM4BcyJA2gLoDc1AX2oQAHumxQwyMAE90KAHLYAkiBjQiAQWSjIIACbNkcEDIoBeWnWSdN3WzpF7Dx08gD8yAAzJ2ICABu0NzU1KCQsIgoeACuAEYAwtgAtuL%204AAKUAzMpABiwAA2EcjmyDEgANYg2ADuIBQ0dAjYhTHJLOxN1gxYuARg7Bh9%20IT5RRFk-Nb0jLhsyEqq6lDjxdBTVgI8-ELCYhJSMBUII8ixiSlpEOBrJWUV1XUNABQA%20uwXSam4N2BZOTuGwAlFQrFBCDEoCBkCAYoVCrtQuFoPAkGg5ixNAAhMF0ODsZhgKCgADm02QcUJxLJSJRkXRwyYzASeDxyAQ1JJIHJVgWRO5vKELRYUgB8kkwAgzBxQ0xAyITPmOIsVFmIwWPGQAn4IqJyHF0Cw0tZcpGCqVLFZqso6uZ7C1OtConEkg58ykAFk4KBvtdwKVkC9QeZGuDIdCg1Y6EQvldfuBo9YWm0OsxzJROEmZrbekwBuxDZLpTiADR2%20ZdYzsABEcRr5apyBrzBr2u15YA9J2OAALYBGZi97Dw-TIWoSSrZ6y5%20WEQvZCXGmXY8t5ytqgnN%20vtgRdnskfuD4ej6S97K1HRQbJQad0Wfm%20cGxdGqUsvBrzELW1buttgQdsg3Z9gOyBDiOhRjmA551FeN7TtwQgzJ2ZBWMCuy8EAA)

Answer (score 0):

Create a **NoInfer** helper type in TypeScript. This type utilizes conditional types to prevent TypeScript from inferring the type too early. Here's how you can integrate **NoInfer** into your code:

```
// Define a NoInfer helper type
type NoInfer<T> = T & { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

// Define a generic interface for option sets
interface OptionSet<T> {
  options: T[];
}

// Define the props for the sub component
interface SubComponentProps<TFilter = unknown> {
  columns: {
    optionSet: OptionSet<TFilter>;
    options: NoInfer<TFilter>; // Use NoInfer here
  }[];
}

// Define the SubComponent function
export function SubComponent<TFilter = unknown>(props: SubComponentProps<TFilter>) {
  return null; // Just a placeholder
}

// Define interfaces for different sets of options
interface OptionsAB {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
interface OptionsCS {
  c: string;
  s: string;
}

// Create option sets for different types of options
const PropertiesAB: OptionSet<OptionsAB> = { options: [] };
const PropertiesCS: OptionSet<OptionsCS> = { options: [] };

// Main component using SubComponent
export const MainComponent = () => {
  return (
    <SubComponent
      columns={[
        { optionSet: PropertiesAB, options: { a: "b", b: "s" } }, // This should work
        // { optionSet: PropertiesAB, options: { a: "b" } }, // This should throw error
        // { optionSet: PropertiesCS, options: { a: "b" } }, // This should throw error
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```